# $3^m$ mod $2^n$: any generic and practical expression?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $m$ and $n$ be integers larger than $3$, potentially really big. I know that the period for $3^m$ mod $2^n$ is about (or exactly ?) $2^{n-2}$.
But I am curious to learn whether or not there is a useable, explicit expression for those classes of $3^m$ in congruence to any $2^n$, especially when $m$ belongs to [ENT$\left(n\cdot\frac{\log2}{\log3}\right)$;$2^{n-2}$] interval ?

Comment: Perhaps $3^m$ is better. $p$ usually is a prime number.

Comment: $3=2+1$. Binomial Theorem

Comment: If you can find the (fundamental) period of $3$ mod $2^n$ as $k$, then the period of $3^m$ is $k/\gcd(k.m)$.

Comment: Thanks @DietrichBurde to correct my notation, I am a newcomer: so now $3^m$, exit p.

Comment: @TheBestMagician, Sorry I do not master your magic... Could you enlighten me a bit and show how the binomial development can make it - since developing $3^m$ will bring a plethora of binomial coeffs and never a power of 2 larger than m.

Comment: Thanks also to @CalvinLin for your quick answer. I am wondering if you have a typo in your statement ? Or maybe I am just blind in those days after so many lavish season meals ;-). Since for any $n>1$ we have 3 congruent to 3 mod $2^n$, and i do not see any period here, other than your $k$ being 1 what you certainly do not meant.

Comment: By "(fundamental) period", I'm guessing you mean "order", IE What is the smallest value of $k$ such that $(3^m)^k \equiv 1 \pmod{2^n}$. If that's not the case, then please clarify what the period is.  If that is the case, please clarify your point about $ 3 \equiv 3 \pmod{8}$.

Comment: I call here "period" the smallest integer $k$ such that $3^{m+k} ≡ 3^m (mod 2^n) $, which holds obviously for every $m$. It is important to understand each other, however my initial question is not about the period (I indicated what I believe to be the value in my post), well about getting an explicit value in the general case for the various classes, if at all possible.

Comment: I don't know if my comment is too useful, but it reduces it to an expression where all powers are less than $n$. Then, based on the $\nu_2$ of the binomial coefficients, you can recover the full residue. Then potentially use Kummer's theorem, but I'm not sure you can express it nicely in the end.

Comment: Thanks for the hint @TheBestMagician, I did not mean to be dismissive, but I am not much optimistic following this route since I do not see how one could recover the cases with $n >> m$ ?